# Unity is showing different physics behaviour while building for different devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on roulette(Casino Style game) game project in Unity3D. 
I am rotating a ball around a wheel and wheel is also rotating on its own axis in fixed update.
I am using transform.RotateAround function to rotate the ball around the wheel and i am also decreasing ball's speed in fixed update.I am assigning a random initial speed to ball within a range such that it always stops on different position each time .

For testing purpose i kept the initial ball speed to constant and check it in unity editor such that every time it rotates it always stops on the same number.
I build this project to android and PC .Though the ball stops on the same number each time in both android and PC build but the result is different in both of them.
For example- Every time ball rotates it stops on number 8 in android and number 20 on Pc each time.

Can somebody please suggest me some ways to obtain same result on different devices?

Why it is happening? Is unity physics behaviour is different in different processor?
and please explain me how to fix that .

Comment: Keep in mind that the physics engine of Unity is non deterministic, so even with the same inputs at a specific time it can have different outputs even on the same machine (due to different floating operations approximations, etc.)

Having said so, can you post the code you're using? How much is your `Fixed Timestep`?

Comment: In order to enhance determinism, you can check 'Enable Enhanced Determinism' in Edit -> Project settings -> Physics -> Enable Enhanced Determinism checkbox. However, Unity does not use integer-based physics, and so can never be deterministic. You will never be able to make a ball bounce the exact same way. Your problem stems from the fact that you probably have not set your target framerate of specifid device builds. There is a huge difference in physics behaviors for apps with 30 and apps with 60 FPS, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a fixed time step, so that isn't the cause of the differences as one might expect. Physics simulations are incredibly complex things, so I'm not going to pretend that I know exactly why you're seeing differences. However, I would imagine it is to do with floating point precision differences between your computer and a much smaller phone processor.

One way to test this would be to run the simulation on another computer, and compare the results to the both of your current devices.